# How to add missing library/header file in C?

Tags: c, dependencies, header-files

A newbie question from python developer, there are few libraries that my c code cannot find. these are:

- sys/socket.h
- netinet/in.h
- arpa/inet.h
- semaphore.h

I'm using MinGW in windows for compiling btw.

In python I can simply install a library (aka 'torch') by command:

`pip3 install torch`

which I'm trying to find a similar commands for C..

Comment: "Include path configuration" is the key here, or `-I` in many compilers, though system headers like that should be in that path by default. Be sure you're using the right header for the *operating system* you're compiling on. Windows has entirely different ideas about what these should be called, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Those are all POSIX header files, so you'll need to be using a POSIX system to get them.  Windows is not POSIX so they're not available there.

You may be able to get access them by using WSL (windows subsystem for linux) which basically installs a linux-like environment on windows (linux is POSIX).  Alternately, you might be able to use cygwin.

mingw explicitly doesn't include any of them, as it tries to be a minimal compiler setup for windows.